# Add custom button to django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin, customization

I want to add button to admin panel to my model, I have overwrite template (path: `templetes/admin/myapp/mymodel/change_list.html`)

change_list.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static %}

{% block result_list %}
<div class="object-tools">
    <a href="{% url 'myurl' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Import</a>
</div>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

In admin.py

```
class ImportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/myapp/mymodel/change_list.html'
```

But I can not see the button.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It works as below ("Import" button right side).

[image]

**Django = 1.11**

admin/change_list.html: Add the URL with "admin:". Otherwise, it will not resolve the URL.

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
{{ block.super }}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'admin:myurl' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Import</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

admin.py: Add the custom template URL

```
class ImportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/myapp/mymodel/change_list.html'
```

**Django >1.8**

settings.py: TEMPLATE_LOADERS [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/). Set TEMPLATES as below.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
                ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                ]),
            ],

        },
    },
]
```

Comment: For Django >3, use `static` instead of `admin_static` (https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/issues/366)

Answer (score 21):

Another option for adding a button would be to use [django-object-actions](https://github.com/crccheck/django-object-actions).

First, install it: `pip install django-object-actions`. (Also add `django-object-actions` to your requirements file if you have one).

Second, add `django_object_actions` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

You can then use it in your `admin.py` like so:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django_object_actions import DjangoObjectActions

class ImportAdmin(DjangoObjectActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def imports(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        print("Imports button pushed")

    changelist_actions = ('imports', )
```

You should now see an Imports button in the admin, and when pressed, the `imports` function defined in `ImportAdmin` will be called.

For more information please refer to:
https://github.com/crccheck/django-object-actions.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to see the button next to `Add` button at the top of list page with the following content.

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'myurl' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Import</a>
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @git-e That is weird. Have you defined your template settings properly?

Comment: I think yes `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)`

Comment: This too looks fine. You have the model registered with admin and configured it correcctly right?