# how to trigger AWS Lambda function with Django framework?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to create a Button with Django Framework and connect to trigger lambda function (aws), click to button to should trigger the function.
Also, another page to upload files to S3 Bucket with django from local.
Should I work on REST API or there is a way around this.

how to get started on this or execute the idea? also helpful if you could share resources on this.

Comment: Are you looking to deploy the Django application to Lambda? Or do you have a Django application deployed somewhere else, but you need to trigger a Lambda function with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lambda client's `invoke()` function from the boto3 package:

```py
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

lambda_payload = {"name":"name","age":"age"}
lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='myfunctionname', 
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=lambda_payload
)
```

Refer to the [official boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) for more info.

You may call the `invoke()` function from your Django admin button. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65741841/9953841) or search similar ones to figure out the Django admin part.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can connect your lambda to an API gateway. The browser hits the API gateway which will trigger your lambda. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

For S3, you can use `boto3` to upload to s3 from inside any Python application. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html